# AWS S3 Bucket make specific folder and all files in it public

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a function in my laravel that uploads and image in my s3 bucket:

```
$disk = Storage::disk('s3');
$disk->put($request->path . '/' . $request->file_name, base64_decode($request->file));
```

The problem is that, the newly uploaded image cannot be accessed.

Now, I have a folder named `public` in my S3 bucket

what I wanted is that by default, `public` folder and all of the images in it(old and newly uploaded) can be accessed publicly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a folder in an Amazon S3 bucket 'public', you can attach a **Bucket Policy** to the bucket:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/my-folder/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This allows *anyone* to retrieve an object (`GetObject`) from the `my-bucket` bucket, if the object is in the `my-folder/` path.

Note that it does *not* allow listing of the bucket. Therefore, they will need to know the exact name of the object to retrieve it.

To add the bucket policy, you will first need to **deactivate S3 Block Public Access** on the bucket to allow bucket policies (the 3rd and 4th options).

An alternative to all the above is to set `ACL=public-read` when creating the files in Amazon S3. This makes the individual object public. (Doing this requires the first two options of **S3 Block Public Access** to be disabled.)

Answer (score 1):

you can go to your AWS console and make these settings at bucket level. Like by defining Policy on the bucket where u can define a folder.